# How to remove escaped characters in filenames?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I would like to remove escaped characters from filenames, so these examples

```
=Web_Help_Desk_Pro%26Lite.pdf
=Windows_7_%2b_s-drev.pdf
```

would become

```
=Web_Help_Desk_ProLite.pdf
=Windows_7__s-drev.pdf
```

Does anyone know how to do this in either Perl or BASH?

Comment: Doesn't a simple `s/%[0-9a-f]{2}//ig` do this? Since it seems you're not looking to decode them, just strip them.

Comment: I suppose. I can do it to the content of files, but I don't know how to do this on the filenames.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to do it on a bunch of files is with the `rename` script that comes with perl: `rename 's/%[0-9a-f]{2}//ig' file1 file2…` on the shell prompt. You can use a shell glob of course (e.g., `dir/*`) or any other way you normally build a list of files in shell (find | xargs, etc.)

Comment: Do you know what perl package that provides `rename`. The `rename` is have is from `util-linux-2.20.1-2.1.fc16.x86_64`.

Comment: Not sure what does on RedHat (its the default rename on Debian), but its just a perl script, so you can [grab it from Debian](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=perl/perl.git;a=blob;f=debian/rename;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just remove the percent sign and the following two hex digits:

```
$path =~ s/%[\da-f][\da-f]//gi;
```

Answer (score 3):

If `$file` is your filename:

```
my $file = '=Web_Help_Desk_Pro%26Lite.pdf';
$file =~ s/%[0-9a-f]{2}//gi;
```

i.e. replace `%` followed by two hex characters with the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
sed 's/%[[:alnum:]]\{2\}//g' INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: `alnum` matches 101,959 different characters instead of the 22 that should be matched.

Comment: Well, in Perl it does. It might be less in `sed`, but it's definitely more than the required 22.

Answer (score 2):

Based on all your help, I came up with

```
for f in $(find . -name \*.html); do
   mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/%[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]//gi')
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the dependency, there is a command '[convmv](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/)':

```
convmv --unescape --notest <files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rename 's/\r//' *.html
```